# Did Sauron's Men vassals worship Morgoth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Silmarillion tells how Sauron made Numenoreans worship Morgoth and offer him human sacrifices.

However, [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Sauron#Second_Age) states that Sauron first created this cult before his Numenorean captivity, for Men tribes of Middle-earth he dominated. There's no citation though. Is it true? Did Sauron's Men vassals in Second Age Middle-earth have Morgoth cult as their religion, and did they perform human sacrifices? Or did they worship Sauron himself as a god?

Also, are there any indications that this practice had survived until War of the Ring?

Comment: Also see [my another question on the purpose of the sacrifices](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/156545/71924).